# Typescript class with private static members + Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have Angular2 app with injectable services, classes, async back-end calls and what not, which wasn't written by be. But somehow I was asked to provide a sort of session control there which previously wasn't implemented.
So I created new class, a really basic one.

```
//EnvConfig.ts:

export class SessionParameters {

private static userId: string = 'EMPTY_USER_ID';
private static userLogin: string = 'EMPTY_USER_LOGIN';
private static callEDUID: string = 'EMPTY_CALL_ID'

static setUserID(userid: string): void {
    SessionParameters.userId = userid;
}

static setUserLogin(usrLogin: string): void {
    SessionParameters.userLogin = usrLogin;
}

static setCurrentCallId(eduid: string): void {
    SessionParameters.callEDUID = eduid;
}

static getUserID(): string {
    return SessionParameters.userId;
}

static getUserLogin(): string {
    return SessionParameters.userLogin;
}

static getCurrentCallId(): string {
    return SessionParameters.callEDUID;
}

static clearSession(): void {
    SessionParameters.userId = 'EMPTY_USER_ID';
    SessionParameters.userLogin = 'EMPTY_USER_LOGIN';
    SessionParameters.callEDUID = 'EMPTY_CALL_ID';
}
```

Nothing special here, alright. Now... I would like to add the session parameters right on app initialization, so I did that:

```
//app.ts:

import { SessionParameters } from 'components/EnvConfig';


@Component({
selector: 'http-app',
template: `
<div class="tcs-parent-container" [ngClass]='cardProduct'>
  <contact-details 
    [cId]='cId'>
  </contact-details>`


class HttpApp {
  constructor (public siebel: CustomerService) {}

....
PostMessageHandler(eventJson: any): void {
...
console.log("Login: "+SessionParameters.getUserLogin());
SessionParameters.setUserLogin(eventJson.params.userLogin);
...
}
```

Okay, that actually worked fine, because I see in browser console this: "Login: EMPTY_USER_LOGIN" on incoming event interaction.
As you can see, there is a "contact-details" selector, into which child component is rendered:

```
//ContactForm.ts:
import { CustomerService } from 'components/CustomerService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

...
constructor (public crv: CustomerService)
...
/*
  subscribe on request's responce execution with implicit observer creation:
    - first parameter: function to invoke for each element in the observable sequence - in our case it's responce from http
    - second parameter: function to invoke upon exceptional termination of the observable sequence
    - third parameter: function to invoke upon graceful termination of the observable sequence 
*/
this.crv
  .searchBackEnd(id, 'contact')
  .subscribe(
    (response: any) => this.renderApplet(response),
    (error: any) => this.crv.logMessage('contact-details',`${this.cId}`,'backend_call_request_error:${error}'),
    () => this.crv.logMessage('contact-details',`${this.cId}`,'backend_call_completed')
  );

...
```

And in child component we use our service for getting things form back-end. Service isn't relevant I guess, apart from this part:

```
  ...
import { BackEndURL, GeneralSettings, SessionParameters } from 'components/EnvConfig';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
...
//method for writig logs back into back-end
logMessage(entityName: string, identifier: string, msg: string): void {

console.log("login_srv: "+SessionParameters.getUserLogin());

//check the switcher
if(GeneralSettings.SERVICE_LOG_ON){

  // time management
  let currDate: Date = new Date();
  let hrs: number = currDate.getHours();
  let mnt: number = currDate.getMinutes();
  let sec: number = currDate.getSeconds();
  let mls: number = currDate.getMilliseconds();
  let timeStr: string = `${hrs}:${mnt}:${sec}:${mls}`;

  // calling http. No callback on subscription
          this.queryWithoutJSONTransform(`${BackEndURL.SERVICE_LOG_ENDPOINT_BRANCH}`, [
    `msg=${SessionParameters.getUserLogin()}||${entityName}||${identifier}||${msg}||${timeStr}||`
  ]).subscribe();

} else {
  //do nothing
}
```

Well, the thing is, the SessionParameters.getUserLogin return undefined here.

So to sum up I see this console output:

```
...
 app.ts:109 Login: EMPTY_USER_LOGIN
2016-12-28 12:35:15.815 CustomerService.ts:49 login_srv: undefined
2016-12-28 12:35:15.821 CustomerService.ts:49 login_srv: undefined
2016-12-28 12:35:15.895 CustomerService.ts:49 login_srv: undefined
...
```

Can anyone explain why private static members are inaccesible inside my service unless specifically set by a setter? It works generally fine, but the problem is exactly with initial static members values of session control class.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, instead of the getter and the setter, what happens if you make the var public and access it directly, e.g. SessionParameters.userId = "harry", and so on. If it's identical at least you know that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Also I could be wrong here, but if the getter and setter is static, and the var is static, do you need to use the class name to access the var in getters and setters? Anyway I think you get the idea that something about the getters and setters seems off to me here. Not to mention, a string variable with a getter and setter that has no processing of the value at all seems to be just a long way around of making it public. One other thing: doesn't typescript use "get" and "set" keywords to mark a method as a getter and setter, e.g. static get myFunc() {}? (I use ES6 for Ang 2 mostly).

Comment: Interesting.    public static test: string = 'TEST_STRING' in EnvConfig.ts works fine. No weird issues in service and app

Comment: I have used private static modifiers to prevent someone from directly setting this variables. Only via class methods call

Comment: Right I get that, but consider whether there is an actual practical effect. What you've set up here is sort of like "I will not hand you the ball directly, I will hand a middleman the ball and he will immediately hand you the ball." The effect is the same as just handing you the ball directly. But if the guy in the middle inspected the ball with the capability to reject it and/or could modify it before passing it, now the middle man actually serves a purpose. 

Not to mention, I read in a couple of places that the TS implementation of getters and setters seems "peculiar" under the hood.

Comment: point taken, but the question still exists :)